# What are the chances for a student to enroll?

Tags: statistics

I'm writing a program for a school and I want to approxmiate the chances that a student will enroll in the school they wanted.

To enroll you have to be in the top $n$ students based on how many points you have. You get points based on your previous grades and a seperate math exam.

Data samples:

[image: hey that's pretty good]

The problem is that the math exam is annonymous and I don't know which code is what student's rank.

> If I have $m$ total points and know the data above, what are the
>   chaces that I will be accepted into the school that accepts only the top $n$ ranked students?

Comment: It's not clear how the math exam is relevant. You said that enrolling is based on points only. Do you just want to estimate the distribution of points so that you can see if you'd be in the top n out of m?

Comment: The grade points and math exam points are summed. Yes, I just want to know if the some stundent is in the top n out of m.

Comment: As the grades and maths are independent you will have to work out all possible ways of combining marks then averaging. Thus all students will have same list of numbers added to their grades, thus average will change but order high to low will not. So why not just ignore maths mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a statistics problem than a maths problem. As with many statistics problems- the answer you get depends on the model you use, I'll give a solution with a simple model but you could make it more accurate if you used more complex analysis.

Students are ranked in order of Grade points + Math points.

Let $X$ be the grade points and $Y$ be the math points.

$Z=X+Y$ is the total points which is what the students are ranked by.

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ have a [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (like a bell-curve). This distribution comes up a lot in applications so I'm using it. With a lot of data you might find that this assumption is not true.

The sample mean of grade points is $71.2$ and the sample variance is $23.9$.

The sample mean of math points is $3.4$ and the sample variance is $2.6$.

When you add together two Gaussian distributed variables the result also Gaussian distributed. Therefore $Z$ has a Gaussian distribution. This assumes that the grade and math points are independent from each other, this assumption is probably wrong since smart students get good grades and good math points. Like I said, you can use a more complex model if you want.

The mean of $Z$ is the mean of $X$ added to the mean of $Y$. $71.2+3.4=74.6$

The variance of $Z$ is the variance of $X$ added to the variance of $Y$. $23.9+2.6=26.5$

So $Z$ has a Gaussian distribution with mean 74.6 and variance 26.5 according to your sample.

Now you know the distribution of the total points you can find the chance that the student is in the top $n$. I'll use an example to show how you can do this:

Suppose $m=50$ and $n=10$. and suppose that a student got 77 grade points and 5 math points.

The student's total points is 82, they are above the average.

Compared to the average for students they are $82-74.6=7.4$ points above average. The standard deviation for points is $\sqrt{26.5}=5.1$, therefore they are $\frac{7.4}{5.1}=1.45$ standard deviations above the mean.

Using an online calculator like [this one](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html) you can see that 1.45 standard deviations above the mean means that they are better than 92.65% of students. There is a 7.35% chance that any student is better than them.

So if there are 49 random students competing with this 1 student what is the chance that 9 or fewer of them are better? This is a binomial distribution, we want to add together the probability that 0 are better plus the probability than 1 is better ... plus the probability that 9 are better.

$\sum_{i=0}^9(0.0735)^i (0.9265)^{49-i}=0.026$

Therefore there is a 2.6% chance that this student gets accepted.